# combine multiple text files into one text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm trying to combine multiple files into one, where each of them contains one column and I need to get one file with two columns and plot the resulted file like (x,y) as follows:

```
x       y       result
1       4       1   4
2       5       2   5
3       6       3   6
```

and run the code for `n` text files.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do all the files contain the same number of rows? and do they contain numbers only (or can be any kind of text)?

Comment: what have you tried so far? any code samples?

Comment: @noamgot - Yes, all of them are numbers and the same number of rows

Comment: @etshooo then you can consider my answer below, it is based on this assumptions

Comment: @noamgot  Ok. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution assuming that all files have the same number of elements in float format.

```
import numpy as np
filename_list=['file0.txt', 'file1.txt']#and so on
columns = []
for filename in filename_list:
    f=open(filename)
    x = np.array([float(raw) for raw in f.readlines()])
    columns.append(x)
columns = np.vstack(columns).T
np.savetxt('filename_out.txt', columns)
```

see also the method [savetxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) to customize the output

EDIT:
if you have 100 files in a certain directory (let's call it `files_dir`) you can use the method `listdir` in the `os` library, be be careful, since `listdir` returns directories and files:

```
import os
filename_list = [f for f in os.listdir(files_dir) if os.path.isfile(f)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much it's working, but if I need to run this code to (for example 100) text files in a specific folder. How could it be?

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I used it but gave me this error:

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'import numpy as np\n'

Comment: I wrote it like this:

filename_list = [f for f in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\output') if os.path.isfile(f)]

Comment: maybe you are also calling your own code file (the file .py), two solutions: add in the if statement "if path.isfile(f) and f[-2:]!='py' " or inside the directory create a new directory and put all files inside it.

Answer (score 0):

here's a quick-and-dirty solution. I assumed that all files have the exact number of rows. The function `write_files` gets an input `files` which is a list of file-paths (strings).

```
def write_files(files):
    opened_files = []
    for f in files:
        opened_files.append(open(f, "r"))

    output_file = open("output.txt", "w")
    num_lines = sum(1 for line in opened_files[0])
    opened_files[0].seek(0,0)
    for i in range(num_lines):
        line = [of.readline().rstrip() for of in opened_files]
        line = " ".join(line)
        line += "\n"
        output_file.write(line)
    for of in opened_files:
        of.close()
    output_file.close()

write_files(["1.txt", "2.txt"])
```

Comment: Thanks in advance, I tried this code but I think it doesn't work with my data or I don't have enough experience to use it