# combine multiple text files with different number of columns separated by tab, into one merged text file in python

Tags: python, for-loop, merge

How to combine multiple txt files into one merged file, where each file contains different number of columns(with Float values ​​usually) and I need to get one merged file with all the columns as follows:

**EDIT:**
there is one rule: In case there is a non-numeric value ("Nan" for example..), I need to do padding according to the last numeric value that was before it.

file1.txt

```
1.04
2.26
3.87
```

file2.txt

```
5.44    4.65    9.86
8.67    Nan     7.45
8.41    6.54    6.21
```

file3.txt

```
6.98    6.52
4.45    8.74
0.58    4.12
```

merged.txt

```
1.04    5.44    4.65    9.86    6.98    6.52
2.26    8.67    8.67    7.45    4.45    8.74
3.87    8.41    6.54    6.21    0.58    4.12
```

I saw here [answer to the case of one column in each file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49474038/combine-multiple-text-files-into-one-text-file).

how can I do this for multiple columns?

Comment: Just one question I didn't consider in my answer. Do you need to keep the number format in the input files and if so, do you know the format in advance?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @BernieD Yes! the number format is Float and I need to keep that format. (There are few cases that the value is not numeric , in that case i should replace it with the last numeric value)

Comment: @u.b I meant the exact representation as a string, in this case as fixed-point number with 2 decimal places.

Comment: @BernieD yes I need the exact representation as a string. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is probably using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

filenames = ["file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt"]
fmt = '%.2f'    # assuming format is known in advance

all_columns = []
for filename in filenames:
    all_columns.append(np.genfromtxt(filename))

arr_out = np.column_stack(tuple(all_columns))  # Stack columns

# Fill NaN-elements with last numeric value
arr_1d = np.ravel(arr_out)  # "flat reference" to arr_out
replaced_all_nan = False
nan_indices = np.where(np.isnan(arr_1d))
while len(nan_indices[0]):
    new_indices = tuple([i-1 for i in nan_indices])
    arr_1d[nan_indices] = arr_1d[new_indices]
    nan_indices = np.where(np.isnan(arr_1d))

np.savetxt("merged.txt", arr_out, fmt=fmt)
```

One problem (if it is one for you) that might occur is that the very first, i.e. the upper-left element, is non-numeric. In that case, the last (lower-right) value or the last numeric value before that would be used.

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry, but there is a rule I forgot to add in the first edit:
In case there is a non-numeric value ("Nan" for example..), I need to do padding according to the last value that was before it.

Comment: I added that to my answer. You just may have to add a rule what happens if the very first (i.e. the zeroth) element is `NaN`.